# how to hide text area value

Tags: javascript, java

I need to set a value in a text area but it  should not display the value in the field. I set the value in java like this

```
gtee.setTxt("Repeat ");
```

Now how to hide the value in the text area

Comment: What should the user see? A `<textarea>` element that they can type in? If you have some other value to store behind the scenes, put it in a `data-` attribute, or if you need it to be submitted put it in an `<input type="hidden">` field.

Comment: <textarea name="hide" style="display:none;"></textarea>

Comment: Why is this tagged java? I know of no `TextArea` class with a `setTxt` method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, two options:

1.Try adding another hidden field to hold the value for that text area.

2.Add a custom attribute that hold data for that text area. E.g.

```
<textarea id="myTextArea" data-customvalue="Your data will be placed here"></textarea>
```

In this case, you can set value for your text area as:

```
$('#myTextArea').data('customvalue', 'Your data');
```